# Protractor how to validate checkbox state with Reactive Forms

Tags: protractor

how to validate checkbox state is checked or not in Reactive Forms:

```
<div class="form-group ng-star-inserted" id="no_empty-group"><label></label><span class="content"><label><input formcontrolname="no_empty" id="no_empty" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="no_empty" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched"> Don't send empty </label></span></div>
```

I do not see any changes on HTML if I check or un-check this checkbox. 
Not sure how to validate in Protractor that checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for elements of `type="checkbox"` this should work:

```
var checkbox = element(by.id('no_empty'));
expect(checkbox.isSelected()).toBe(false); // unchecked
checkbox.click();
expect(checkbox.isSelected()).toBe(true);  // checked
```